# Please vs Kindly

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, politeness, imperative-sentences

The word "please" is similar to "kindly". But somehow when I thought of using them, the approach is kind of different.

When using "please" you'd like to ask for assistance. While using "kindly", somehow seems like giving a direct command.

Do they really have difference or it just has to do with how you deliver it?

Comment: **I kindly ask you to leave the room *(if you don't, I'll throw you out).*** **Please, leave the room *(If you don't, I will ask kindly)***

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the nuance you describe.  Using the word, "kindly", implies that you are obligated to comply.  Using the word, "please", implies that your compliance is optional. 
However, if a person, in-authority, uses the word, "please", they may be politely communicating your obligation to comply.